# How much cash per person may we bring from South Africa to Switzerland?

Tags: money, switzerland, south-african-citizens, western-europe

When travelling from South Africa To Switzerland as a family of 6, what is the amount of cash as a family we are allowed to take on us?

Comment: Are you concerned how much you can import, export or both? I remember SA is quite strict on exporting funds.

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation is here: http://www.ezv.admin.ch/zollinfo_privat/04414/04415/index.html?lang=en

> In the case of liquid funds of CHF 10,000 or more, an entry will be made in the information system of the Customs Administration. If there is a suspicion of money laundering or terrorist financing, the funds may be temporarily confiscated or handed over to the police.

10K CHF is about 10K USD, and this line between "We don't care" and "We might care" is pretty consistent between many countries (it's often roughly 10K USD in whatever local currency).

So you can bring 60K CHF with no questions asked.  Hopefully that's enough!

Comment: If you bring that much, do not have one person carry it all. Generally that is not something customs people like to see.